# Import output of kubectl get pods -o json in to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, kubernetes

I'd like to import the output of:

```
kubectl get pods -o json
```

into a python pandas dataframe. This should contain also all containers and there resource request and limits.

My code starts as follows:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
pods_raw = os.popen('kubectl get pods -o json').read()
pods_json = json.loads(pods_raw)['items']
```

from here on I struggle to get the data in a correct way in a dataframe, especially the 'spec.containers' should be split up when multiple containers exist.

Comment: can you show us what code you tried, the expected result and the actual result?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can extract the data of interest to the dataframe. The output is only an example (as you didn't specify the required output in the question):

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

# open the Json data from file (or use os.popen):
with open("data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

df = pd.DataFrame(data["items"])

# metadata:
df = pd.concat(
    [df, df.pop("metadata").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("meta_")], axis=1
)

# spec:
df = pd.concat(
    [df, df.pop("spec").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("spec_")], axis=1
)

# status:
df = pd.concat(
    [df, df.pop("status").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("status_")], axis=1
)


# keep only columns of interests:
df = df[["meta_name", "meta_namespace", "status_phase", "spec_containers"]]

# explode spec_containers column
df = df.explode("spec_containers")
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.pop("spec_containers")
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .add_prefix("spec_")[["spec_image", "spec_name"]],
    ],
    axis=1,
)


print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                        meta_name meta_namespace status_phase                                                                spec_image                  spec_name
0                      apache-lb-648c5cb8cb-mw5zh        default      Running                                                                     httpd                     apache
0                      apache-lb-648c5cb8cb-mw5zh        default      Running                                      index.docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.13.4                istio-proxy
1                          csi-cephfsplugin-fc79l        default      Running  rocks.canonical.com:443/cdk/sig-storage/csi-node-driver-registrar:v2.0.1           driver-registrar
1                          csi-cephfsplugin-fc79l        default      Running                        rocks.canonical.com:443/cdk/cephcsi/cephcsi:v3.3.1           csi-cephfsplugin
1                          csi-cephfsplugin-fc79l        default      Running                        rocks.canonical.com:443/cdk/cephcsi/cephcsi:v3.3.1        liveness-prometheus


...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have the following code to solve this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import pandas as pd
import os

kb = 1024
mb = kb * kb
gb = mb * kb
tb = gb * kb

def main():
    pods_raw = os.popen('kubectl get pods -A -o json').read()
    pods_json = json.loads(pods_raw)['items']
    first_split = ['status','metadata','spec']
    second_split = ['spec.containers','spec.containers.resources',"spec.containers.resources.limits","spec.containers.resources.requests"]
    df_pods = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pods_json)

    df_pods = concat_data(df_pods, first_split)

    df_pods = expand_data(df_pods, ['spec.containers'])

    df_pods = concat_data(df_pods, second_split)
    df_pods.index
    df_pods.index.name='index'
    col_to_normalize = ['spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu',
                        'spec.containers.resources.limits.memory',
                        'spec.containers.resources.requests.cpu',
                        'spec.containers.resources.requests.memory']

    for col_name in col_to_normalize:
        df_pods[col_name] = df_pods[col_name].map(normalize_values)
    df_pods[col_to_normalize] = df_pods.groupby('index')[col_to_normalize].sum()
    df_pods = df_pods.drop_duplicates(['metadata.name'])
    df_pods[df_pods['status.phase'] == 'Running']

    print(df_pods)


def concat_data(df: pd.DataFrame, expands: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    for expantion in expands:
        # df = pd.concat( [df, df.pop(expantion).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(f"{expantion}.")], axis=1)
        df = pd.concat( [df, df.pop(expantion).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(f"{expantion}.")], axis=1)
    return df

def expand_data(df: pd.DataFrame, expands: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    for expantion in expands:
        s = df[expantion].apply(pd.Series).stack()
        s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
        s.index
        df.index = [x for x in df.index]
        del df[expantion]
        s.name = expantion
        df=df.join(s)
    return df

def normalize_values(val: str) -> int:
    try:
        if val[-1] == 'm':
            return int(val[:-1]) / 1000
        if val[-2].lower() == "k":
            return int(val[:-2]) * kb
        if val[-2].lower() == "m":
            return int(val[:-2]) * mb
        if val[-2].lower() == "g":
            return int(val[:-2]) * gb
        if val[-2].lower() == "t":
            return int(val[:-2]) * tb
        return int(val)
    except:
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works fine except for the following FutureWarning I get and don't know how to solve this yet:

```
./resources.py:43: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
```

df = pd.concat( [df, df.pop(expantion).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(f"{expantion}.")], axis=1)